# Android Studio gradle build failed: Could not resolve all files for configuration:app:debugRuntime Classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i am facing this issue for 3 days and can't solve it i tried maximum available solution but it not solve i hope hare i find som solution

I am using a DensoSacnner sdk(dependency)

i have tried toggle online or offline mode but the solution is not working i have tried many solution but not solve

Comment: Without more information we cannot help you, what does your build.gradle look like for example?

Comment: post the whole error stacktrace, your build.gradle and only then we will be able to help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.